# MySQL join 3 tables and format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I am trying to call 3 different tables and join them together into one array. This is what I have:

```
$this->db->select('so_alcohol.id, 
    so_alcohol.name as name, 
    so_alcohol.category as category, 
    so_alcohol.permName as permName,
    so_alcohol.picture as alcoholPicture, 
    group_concat(so_user.firstName) as firstName,
    group_concat(so_user.lastName) as lastName,
    group_concat(so_user.picture) as userPicture,
    group_concat(so_rating.idUser) as idUser,
    group_concat(so_rating.overall) as overall,
    group_concat(so_rating.description) as description');
$this->db->from('alcohol');
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
$this->db->join('so_rating', 'so_rating.idAlcohol = so_alcohol.id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('so_user', 'so_user.id = so_rating.idUser', 'LEFT');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

The output I would like is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Product Name
                    [category] => Product category
                    [permName] => Product-Name
                    [alcoholPicture] => http://image.com/1.jpg
                    [idUser] => 1,2,3
                    [overall] => 100,80,50
                    [description] => Review 1,Awesome review 2, Horrible review 3
                    [firstName] => name 1, name 2, name 3
                    [lastName] => last 1, last 2, last 3
                    [userPicture] => http://userimage.com/1.jpg, http://userimage.com/2.jpg, http://userimage.com/3.jpg
                )
    [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Product Name
                    [category] => Product category
                    [permName] => Product-Name
                    [alcoholPicture] => http://image.com/1.jpg
                    [idUser] => 1,2,3
                    [overall] => 100,80,50
                    [description] => Review 1,Awesome review 2, Horrible review 3
                    [firstName] => name 1, name 2, name 3
                    [lastName] => last 1, last 2, last 3
                    [userPicture] => http://userimage.com/1.jpg, http://userimage.com/2.jpg, http://userimage.com/3.jpg
                )  

)
```

My question is how do I make what I have work, right now there are two problems (that I have found) First it only outputs 1 result, I need it to output 40 and second I cant `so_user.id = so_rating.idUser` because I already `group_concat(so_rating.idUser)`Any Ideas? I am not even sure if this is the right way of doing it as I am still a php newbie.

EDIT:

Alcohol

```
id        name           category        permName        picture
1         Product #1     1               Product-1       http://someurl.com/1.jpg
2         Product #2     1               Product-2       http://someurl.com/2.jpg
3         Product #3     1               Product-2       http://someurl.com/3.jpg
4         Product #4     2               Product-2       http://someurl.com/4.jpg
```

Rating

```
id        idUser        idProduct        overall        description
1         1             2                100            Great Product Review 1
2         2             2                75             Great Product Review 2      
3         1             3                100            Great Product Review 3     
4         2             3                98             Great Product Review 4
```

User

```
id        firstName        lastName        userPicture  
1         first 1          last 1          http://someurlUserPicture.com/1.jpg            
2         first 2          last 2          http://someurlUserPicture.com/2.jpg                 
3         first 3          last 3          http://someurlUserPicture.com/3.jpg                
4         first 4          last 4          http://someurlUserPicture.com/4.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you provide some table schematics to work with? i also don't see any `GROUP BY` in your query. i assume you want to `GROUP BY so_alcohol.id`? if you want to group only by `so_alcohol.id` you will have to use an aggregate function on the remaining columns like `max(so_alcohol.name) as name`. [further reading about max()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373395/getting-info-from-two-mysql-tables/9374416#9374416)

your second problem is really none. you can join on any available column even if you don't decide to have it in the result. example:

```
SELECT
    MAX(customer.email) AS email,
    MAX(customer.name) AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(address.country) AS countries
FROM
    customer
JOIN
    /* customer.address_id is not in the SELECT-clause, 
       but you can still use the column to join */
    address ON customer.address_id = address.id 
GROUP BY
    customer.id
```

if you are thinking about splitting the value of firstName into single names afterwards, don't. have mysql produce one user per row and do the grouping in PHP while outputting.

Edit1: Example on GROUP BY

TABLE product

```
id   name
1    Product1
2    Product2
```

TABLE rating

```
rating_id   product_id
1           1
2           1
3           2
```

Join

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
JOIN rating ON product.id = rating.product_id
```

outputs

```
id   name        rating_id   product_id
1    Product1    1           1
1    Product1    2           1
2    Product2    3           2
```

adding a `GROUP BY id`-clause

```
SELECT 
    id,
    MAX(name) AS name,
    COUNT(rating_id) AS rating_count
FROM product 
JOIN rating ON product.id = rating.product_id
GROUP BY id
```

will put all tuples that have the same value in the column `id` into one group:

```
id   name        rating_count
1    Product1    2
2    Product2    1
```

you are not allowed to select columns in your result, which you do not group by or use aggregate functions on. but mysql will let this slip and provide you with a reasonable result anyway.

hope that mini-tutorial works. if not i suggest to get to know SQL better before you continue to use codeigniter. if you don't understand what codeigniter does behind the curtains, you will not be able to control your output.

Comment: I put up the table schematics. As per what your asking I am not sure what the group by function would do....I am still really green with php/msql my hope was to plunge into making a site to learn what I need to learn. The second part I always get an error in Mysql saying I cant do `so_user.id = so_rating.idUser` because I `GROUP_CONCAT` it earlier. Do you mind showing me an example of how you would tackle this now that I put up the table schematic?

Comment: Nevermind I am an idiot, I did not put a , at the end. ok the second part works but I am still only getting 1 alcohol, 1 review and 1 user. I want to get 40 alcohols, 5 reviews and 5 users

Comment: add `$this->db->group_by("so_alcohol.id");` before executing your query. i found that if you don't have a group by statement in your query but use group_concat nonetheless, mysql will simply group by NULL and produce one big group, which is in fact just one row.

Comment: i added a small explanation on how the group by-clause works. good luck.

Comment: Awesome that did the trick, 1 last question is there a way that I can instead of separating the group_concat by , would there be a way to put them in a nested array? Or should I just do this in php later?

Comment: there is not. results of sql-queries are always two dimensional tables. if you want to have some kind of tree-structure, you will have to create this in php. just remove the group_by-call and the group_concats in your query. keep the order_by("alcohol.id") and loop over the tuples in php. while looping remember the current alcohol.name and every time it changes, you have a new group. i suggest to play around with this problem because it's very common.

Comment: Hey I thought of one more thing, how would I limit the the amount of reviews/users that get called to only the latest 5?

Comment: Use SQL: `LIMIT 5`. You can insert this in your query with `$this->db->limit(5);`. If you need the next 5 Tuples after that, write `LIMIT 5, 5` or `$this->db->limit(5, 5);` or in general `$this->db->limit($startWithTupleNumber, $amountOfTuples);`. Which of the tuples will be the first 5 is determined by your `ORDER BY`-clause.

Comment: Question I wanna limit the amount of alcohols to 40 but limit the amount of users and reviews to 5, if I did just limit(5) then wouldn't that also limit the alcohol's? Can I limit by tables?

Comment: you can produce this kind of result with correlated subqueries. but don't do this. mysql does not optimize this kind of query well, or mostly at all. the tool you would need for this task is a so called sliding window. google `"sliding window dwh"` for more information, but beware that mysql does not support this.

Comment: if you don't care about what user tuples get selected for your "just 5", you could create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`-kind of table and update it manually every time you create a new product or a product with less than 5 reviews get's reviewed. in this `materialized view`-table you would have every product and 5 user joined to each product.

Comment: another approach is to have reviews numbered. each first review for a product would have the number 1, the second number 2 and so on. you can then simply get the first 5 reviews with a simple `WHERE`-clause `WHERE review_number BETWEEN 1 AND 5`. if you want the 5 newest you could save the highest review number for each product and do `WHERE review_numnber BETWEEN alcohol.highest_review_number AND alcohol.highest_review_number-4`.